# how to justify the logistic function is the inverse of the natural logit function?

Tags: logarithms, machine-learning

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Logistic_differential_equation)

> The logistic function is the inverse of the natural logit function

The standard logistic function looks like (equation_1)

$$
{\displaystyle 
{\begin{aligned}
f(x)&={\frac {1}{1+e^{-x}}}={\frac {e^{x}}{e^{x}+1}}={\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{2}}\tanh({\frac {x}{2}})\\
\end{aligned}}}
$$

the natural logit function looks like (equation_2)

$$logit(p) = \log\left(\dfrac{p}{1-p}\right)$$

how to justify equation_1 is the inverse of equation_2?

Comment: maybe you can write $x= \frac{1}{1+e^{-y}}$ and solve for $y$ ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

let $y = logit(x) = log \dfrac{x}{1-x}$

$e^y = \dfrac{x}{1-x}$

$1 + e^y = \dfrac{1-x}{1-x} + \dfrac{x}{1-x} = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$

$\dfrac{1}{1 + e^y} = 1 - x$

$x = 1 - \dfrac{1}{1 + e^y} = \dfrac{e^y}{1 + e^y}$

Answer (score 4):

just calculate $f\big(\operatorname{logit}(p)\big)=p$ and $\operatorname{logit}\big(f(x)\big)=x$;
$$f\big(\operatorname{logit}(p)\big) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1-p}{p}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{p}}=p$$and$$\operatorname{logit}\big(f(x)\big)=\log\left(\frac{\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}}{1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}}\right)=\log\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}-1}\right)=\log\left(e^x\right)=x.$$